# How to configure Auth component in appcontroller

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, authorization, acl

I am using cakephp 2.6.

I have followed the tutorials from cakephp's cookbook and found that there are two ways to configure Auth component in appcontroller.

The first one is:

```
public $components = array(
  'Acl',
  'Auth' => array('authorize' => array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'))),
  'Session'
);
```

And another is:

```
public $components = array(
  'Acl',
  'Auth' => array('authorize' => 'Controller'),
  'Session'
);
```

So my question is: What are the differences between them and why we should use **authorize** parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public $components = array(
    'Cookie',
    'Email',
    'RequestHandler',
    'Session' ,
    'Auth'=>array(
        'loginAction' => '/login',
        'loginRedirect'=> '/login', //~ where to redirect if user not login
        'logoutRedirect'=> '/logout',
        'authError'=>"You can't access this page",

        'authenticate' => array('Form',array('fields' => array('username' => 'email'),'userModel' => 'User')), //~ user email as username if login with email else use username in case of log
        'authorize'=>array('Controller')    
    ) ,
    'RequestHandler',
    'Upload'
);
```

put this function in app controller

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if($user)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You cans login with useing below code in login function

```
$this->Auth->login();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but basically I want to know why I should use authorize parameter that is **'authorize'=>array('Controller') **

Comment: You will find your answer here. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authorization